# Installing Protobuf Development Libraries in MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers

I installed Protobuf in MinGW from the sources on github.

When I try to compile my C++ program I get errors:

```
CMakeFiles/nxcore_interface.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_E[.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_E]+0x0): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I found something that indicates the development libs are not present:

[Program with protocol-buffers don't compile with MinGW-w64: "undefined reference to google::protobuf:: ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436386/program-with-protocol-buffers-dont-compile-with-mingw-w64-undefined-reference)

I have included the `-lprotobuf` compiler flag.

After some searching I determined I need to use `libprotobuf-dev`   but I am having trouble locating it.

**Does anyone know where to get it, or is something else wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

You should compile your application with pkg-config.

```
g++ my_program.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`
```

If you don't have pkg-config you should locate libraries path and set them with -L option. Eg:

```
g++ my_program.cpp -L/usr/local/protobuf/lib -lprotobuf
```

Comment: My libraries are in `/usr/local/lib` I tried using `-L/usr/local/lib` but same error.

Comment: Also helps if you know how to do this in CMake.