# libprotobuf.a linker errors

Tags: protocol-buffers, linker-errors

I am trying to recreate an environment for a  C++ program that uses google's `protobuf 3.5.1.1`. I have built protobuf using MinGW, and all seems well. When I run the `make check` command, I get 5 passes and 1 fail (protobuf-test.exe fails).

The commands that I run in MSYS2 are:

`./autogen.sh`

`./configure`

`make`

`make check`

When I try to build the program that uses protobuf, I get a massive wall of linker errors.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue is appreciated.

Thank you!

----- Edit -----

To solve this issue, I needed to update make protobuf in the `MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit` terminal.

I also needed to update MSYS2 by [following these directions](https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cross compiling in a linux environment then running your make install through msys2 on windows platform.

./configure --help will display a list of flags you can include. Specifically --target="your desired target"

Comment: Will try. What flags do you recommend adding to the `./configure` @Noble?

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436386/program-with-protocol-buffers-dont-compile-with-mingw-w64-undefined-reference . you can add  ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32 --with-protoc=protoc LDFLAGS='-static'

Comment: You can also check the protobuf github to check the current build status for each platform. It looks like windows is having troubles with building.

Comment: I tried using that flag, and it didn't work. I read online to use the flags `--host=i686-w64-mingw32.static LDFLAGS='-static'`, so I will try that now

Comment: You might also try compiling in cygwin instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991975/protobuf-3-0-0-alpha-1-not-compiling-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: After successfully compiling protobuf in linux using the flags `--host=i686-w64-mingw32.static LDFLAGS='-static'` I linked a program to the libprotobuf.a and I get an even bigger wall of errors.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/V7gjNPccERw . Try cmake with cygwin. Do you know specific errors you are getting?

Comment: Trying now to build in Cygwin with cmake. As for the errors, they seem to be linker errors for the libprotobuf.a. I'll report back on how the Cygwin build went.

Comment: No luck with cmake on Cygwin or cross compiling. I was trying to fix an issue where Cygwin didn't recognize the '\r' character in the `./autogen.sh`. I was able to cross compile with the configure flags `--target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr`, but I was unable to install

Comment: I found out my issue. the problem was that I needed to update pacman (as specified [here](https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2)) and I needed to build protobuf in the `MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit` terminal. Thank you for your help!!!